# BigQuery count distinct ColX is not equal to count of group by ColX

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have been under the impression that if you were to do a `COUNT(DISTINCT xyz)` on some column, it would be equal to the regular count of a `GROUP BY` that column.

However, when I do that over a very large dataset in BigQuery, with the exact same conditions, it is showing a large difference in results:

```
Query Type             Count
----------------------------------
- count(distinct ColX)   > 7 million
- count(ColX)
    ... GROUP BY ColX    ~ 6.5 million
```

Why is this? Was I wrong to think these two different versions of counting unique values in a column should return the same count result?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On Legacy SQL.

If you use the DISTINCT keyword, the function returns the number of distinct values for the specified field. **Note that the returned value for DISTINCT is a statistical approximation and is not guaranteed to be exact - the documentation is also clear about this.**

If you require greater accuracy from COUNT(DISTINCT), you can specify a second parameter, n, which gives the threshold below which exact results are guaranteed. By default, n is 1000, but if you give a larger n, you will get exact results for COUNT(DISTINCT) up to that value of n. However, giving larger values of n will reduce scalability of this operator and may substantially increase query execution time or cause the query to fail.

To compute the exact number of distinct values, use `EXACT_COUNT_DISTINCT`. Or, for a more scalable approach, consider using GROUP BY on the relevant field(s) and then applying COUNT(*). The GROUP BY approach is more scalable but might incur a slight up-front performance penalty.

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/query-reference#aggfunctions

Comment: makes perfect sense. is `DISTINCT` a statistical approximation for all databases that use that? or is this just a bigquery thing?

Comment: Just a BigQuery thing.

Comment: Is this just legacy sql? Or standard as well? Standard doco does not seem to talk about this.